# How to find the line of memory leak in Memory Analyze Tool in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have a code with some memory leaks. I've found **Memory Analyze Tool (MAT)** which is said to be one of the best for Java. It looks fancy and gives a lot of details for problems, so much information about them. However, it doesn't say the first thing to be said or I couldn't find.

Let say my code is as follow:

```
class LeakyClass{
    //do some stuff in thousands of lines 
    void leaky_method(){
        char[] chars = //some how cause memory leak --> line 12434
    }
    //do more stuff in thousands of lines 
}
```

Consider, there are 30-40 more classes like this and it is not written by me.

The problem is `MAT` tells that I have problems with `char[]` but it doesn't say anything about `line 12434` or I'm not able to find. Is there a way to find `that line` or at least `class` or `method` name? If there was only one line, I'd search for the line but leaks might be everywhere?

Here is an image for memory-leaks:
[image: mem-leak]

By the way, I read couple of tutorial but couldn't find anything about it.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have an HPROF heap dump, then this information is not available. You need a profiling agent that records allocation stack traces for each allocation.

For example, [JProfiler](http://ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has this capability. Activate allocation recording in the session startup dialog and then take a heap dump.

In the "Classes" view of the heap walker, select "char[]" and create a new object set. Then go to the "Allocations" tab of the heap walker, and check the cumulated stack traces of all such allocations.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.